# IONIC Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to start a new Ionic 3 application. 
`ionic start projectName blank`
but I keep getting this error:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:**********\Desktop\Ionic2\FirstProject\ionic.config.json.1795665366'

I'm running node.js command prompt as an **Administrator**

Comment: Run: npm cache clean

Comment: I did that already, still same error